# Filter date to search PLC Projects

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that i need to set up a date filter that will pull the project numbers in a `listbox` within that date range so the user can click on the project number and go to that project.

Comment: Please share your code. What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: No. Please click on the edit button on your question, and add the code there. Relying on external links is discouraged.

Comment: I dont know what code to perform this task